# How to Disable past years in datetime_select in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want disable all past years in datetime_select, but cannot find any way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
datetime_select("article", "written_on", start_year: Time.now.year)
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-datetime_select